# Oracle Composite Range-Hash Partitioning

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I am trying to partition my table as below

```
CREATE  TABLE ABC(
id VARCHAR2(100) primary key,
datecreated DATE)
PARTITION BY RANGE (datecreated) INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1,'DAY'))
  SUBPARTITION BY HASH (ID) SUBPARTITIONS 4
 (PARTITION lessthan2018  VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP' 2018-01-01 00:00:00') );
```

If I use WHERE clause with column "ID" will the performance improve? Will the performance be the same if I just partition by date. Will it perform the same since ID is already a primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `id` is the primary key then you will have a unique global index on that column, and partitioning will not make any difference because the index already takes you to the physical address of the specified row.

Also, dropping, truncating or exchanging a partition will invalidate the index unless you specify the `update global indexes` clause.

If `id` was not the PK but something non-unique like a product type, or area code, then a query for just that column without any date would need to check every partition.

Comment: Does it make any difference to the performance, if i HASH the subpartition

Comment: Compared to what? My comments above were about hash subpartitioning.

Comment: Hash (sub)partitioning helps if you access the key without `INDEX ACCESS`. You will `FULL TABLE SCAN` only the (sub)partition that contains the key.